# Spring Boot - searching category tree

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, repository

I am writing Spring Boot application which is basically advertisement service. In database (I use PostgreSQL dialect) I store tree of categories. Each category holds a reference to its immediate parent. Each advertisement has his category assigned and for the sake of the problem, you can assign an advertisement only to leaf category.

An image below captures the structure.

[Category tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eVBy.png)

Now I need to retrieve advertisements of specific category from database. But let's say I want to retrieve all advertisements of category E. That means I want to retrieve advertisements of categories which are children of category E, but not necessarily immediate children. In this case I would like to retrieve advertisements of categories G, H, I and J because they are all leafs and they are all children of category E.

How can I achieve it via Spring repository? Here are simplified entity classes for this example.

Category...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "cat_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "cat_name", length = 50, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cat_parent", referencedColumnName = "cat_id", nullable = false)
    private Category parent;

    ...
}
```

... and Advertisement.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "advertisements")
public class Advertisement {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "adv_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "adv_title", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "adv_description", length = 5000, nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "adv_category", referencedColumnName = "cat_id", nullable = false)
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "adv_owner", referencedColumnName = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User owner;

    ...
}
```

Comment: You can write a native query using Postgres Common Table Expressions (CTEs). See the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html).

Comment: @manish I haven't ever used it, I'll check it. I suppose it has something to do with those recursive queries? It doesn't look particularly easy.

Comment: there are two ways to create hierarchical data structures. When an object in the structure holds a reference to its direct parent, the structure is said to be an `Adjacency list`. The other option is to model the structure as a `Nested set`. Finding leaf nodes in a nested set is trivial and requires a very simple SQL query. However, construction of nested sets is complex and they are practically useful only when the hierarchy tree is mostly static and does not need to change often. Do read up on these two models to see if nested sets are a solution for your problem.

Comment: @manish Well, once I create categories tree, probably I am not going to change it. This is merely project for my master thesis, it doesn't need to be perfect. So `Nested set`sounds like viable solution. Still, `Adjacency tree` seems to be much more elegant. I found a native SQL query to retrieve all leafs from root, but I failed to modify it so it would return leaf nodes of any subtree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant way to do this, but you could just collect the bag of categories first and then query the advertisement repository using *in clause* that limits the results to advertisements in those categories only.

First add the other end of the parent/child association to the Category object if it's not there already, and create a method that returns a set that contains that category and all the children (not just the immediate ones) something like:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "cat_parent")
@OneToMany
Set<Category> children;
... 
public Set<Category> collectLeafChildren() { 
   Set<Category> results = new HashSet<>(); 
   if (children.isEmpty()) { 
      results.add(this); 
   } else { 
      children.forEach(child -> { 
        results.addAll(child.collectLeafChildren()); 
      }); 
   } 
   return results; 
}
```

Then create a new method to the `Advertisement` repository that returns all advertisements for given set of categories like:

```
List<Advertisement> findByCategoryIn(Set<Category> categories);
```

And use those:

```
Set<Category> categories = category.collectLeafChildren();
List<Advertisement> advertisementRepository.findByCategoryIn(categories);
```

Comment: This one seems to be the simplest solution, which is not bad at all. The project doesn't require the best one. The problem is, I already mapped the other end of association (parent). I heard it is not good to hold both ends of association. I could remove parent but I'm not sure whether I'll need it in the future or not...

Comment: Good to know, i'm not sure why holding the both ends of an association would prove to be a problem? I've done it couple of times and got away with it ;) For performance consideration, by default the parent relation (ManyToOne) is eagerly loaded and children (OneToMany) is lazy. You could further control how these relations are mapped using entity graphs or join fetching in query

Comment: I dunno, I'm just getting into JPA stuff, but my teacher once told me that we should avoid holding two ends of association, one is enough. By the way, I needed to change your method a little - I need only leaf categories that are children to given one, I don't categories that are between.

`public Set<Category> collectLeafChildren() {
 Set<Category> results = new HashSet<>();
 if (children.isEmpty()) {
  results.add(this);
 } else {
  children.forEach(child -> {
   results.addAll(child.collectLeafChildren());
  });
 }
 return results;
}`

Sorry about formatting.

Comment: I guess it is a bit more tedious to maintain both ends. For example if you're adding a new child to parent you should make sure that the child references the parent AND make sure that the child is in the parents bag of children. Updated the answer with new code example (only leafs)

Comment: @Patryk - did you end up using this or some other solution to your problem? if it helped you please accept the answer, thanks!

Comment: My colleague from work suggested different solution since category tree will be static, i.e. I won't add or change categories once I added them to DB. I'll just create join table with cat_id and leaf_id so I can store leaves for each category. It's not very portable solution and it works only because category tree is static. But retrieving leaves should be more efficient than calling collectLeafChildren() recursively. Anyway, your solution helped me to understand the problem so it is fair to accept it. Thank you. :)